# each over the result of a helper function?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

In handlebars I have registered a helper function that returns a list, for example:

```
function myHelper() {
    return [
        'some val 1',
        'some val 2',
        'some val 3'
    ]
}
```

I would like to call that function and iterate over the results using Handlebars, something like this:

```
{{#each myHelper}}
<li>{{this}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

However this does not call my function, I presume it is looking for a variable in the context called `myHelper` and not the function.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to add the result of `myHelper()` to the context as a variable before the page is rendered?

I'm using Node, Express and [handlebars-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript functions are object so in theory you could do this (is not tested).

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('each', function(context, options) {

   // Execute context if it's a function to get the array
   if(typeof context == "function")
     context = context();
  
  var ret;
  
  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret += options.fn(context[i]);
  }

  return ret;
});
```

Then in your code...

```js
function myHelper() {
    return [
        'some val 1',
        'some val 2',
        'some val 3'
    ]
}

var context = {myHelper: myHelper};
var html    = template(context);
```

Comment: Nice solution. This appears to work when the helper function is defined in the context but when it is defined as a global helper the passed function argument comes in as undefined.